# Can someone explain how Object.defineProperty work in constructor function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I create a very simple object **Person** and calling constructor with a `name` parameter, as i haven't created any local variables inside **Person** constructor, then how `name` property gets set.

```
function Person(name) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
        get: function() {
            return name;
        },
        set: function(newName) {
            debugger;
            name = newName;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    this.sayName = function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    };
}

var p1 = new Person("mike");
```

how `name` property get set ?

Comment: it just uses the `name` argument.

Comment: you can use p1.name="test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't created any local variables inside `Person` constructor

`name` is a local variable, declared by the `name` parameter of your function. This variable is used in the setter and getter of the `.name` property.

Comment: name is a local variable, so what ?? can you explain ?

Comment: @Cody: What didn't you understand? How getters and setters work?

Comment: when i call constructor set method is used to set name ??

Comment: No, when the constructor is called then the property is declared. The setter is called when you assign to the property, the getter is called when you access the property.

Comment: So when i call constructor with name parameter and i used Object.defineproperty to define name property that's why it set to name?

Comment: It is because you call it with the property name `"name"`, and use the local `name` variable in your setter/getter - to store the value for the property.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways that variable references are kept long-term in JavaScript; as object properties (`myObj = {x: 3}`, x is a simple property of myObj), and through a JavaScript internal system called "closures" that takes local variables and maintains their reference as long as a function can still access them (like your property accessors).

Examples of local variables would be as follows:

```
function myFunction(localVariable1) {
  var localVariable2 = ...
  ...
}
```

If myFunction runs once and ends, the garbage collector gets rid of localVariable1 and localVariable2 when the function finishes; it doesn't need them. A useful trick in JavaScript though, is the fact that the compiler can keep variable references even inside a function, if an *inner* function will need them.

```
function myFunction(localVariable1) {
  document.onload = function() {
    document.write(localVariable1;
  };
}
```

In that case, it will keep a reference to localVariable1 until document onload (and perhaps after since the function still exists). In your case though, it will keep it for the entire length of the object so that those set and get functions can operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

to call the setter use p1.name="test" ;

and for getter p1.name;

see this example [Example: Custom Setters and Getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
function Archiver() {
  var temperature = null;
  var archive = [];

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'temperature', {
    get: function() {
      console.log('get!');
      return temperature;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      console.log("set:"+value);
      temperature = value;

      archive.push({ val: temperature });
    }
  });

  this.getArchive = function() { return archive; };
}

var arc = new Archiver();
arc.temperature; // 'get!'
arc.temperature = 11;
arc.temperature = 13;
arc.getArchive(); // [{ val: 11 }, { val: 13 }]
```

console results

```
 get!
 set:11
 set:13
```